# Google playstore App downloading status

Tags: android

I am downloading a app from my application, for that I am going

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.digiplex.game"));
startActivity(intent);
```

and I am comming back to my app.
I want to know status of app anytime like how much app has been downloading or it is downloading or not.

Comment: Isn't that what the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) is for?

Comment: DownloadManager is to notify same application while in my case, Android market app is downloading and I want to know in my application is app being downloading or cancelled or downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is no way out because all the downloading managed by marketing app. which does not expose progress.